# How to transpose a filtered column of data in Excel Macro (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, filter, transpose

I have recorded a macro to filter a large column of data (to remove the duplicates) and i want to transpose it to create a matrix for analysis purposes. For some reason the Macro will record the 'PasteSpecial' but gives me a 'Run-time error 1004' when I try to execute it.
I realise there is only 256 columns in excel(03) but this currently has less unique values than that. The run time error occurs at the 'selection.PasteSpecial...'

```
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C1:C574").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need **Copy / PasteSpecial:**

```
Sub lexhtu8()
    Range("C1:C574").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    k = 4
    For i = 1 To 574
        If Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            Cells(1, k).Value = Cells(i, "C").Value
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't seem to find another way to transpose but you have shown you can!